# java.lang.SecurityException when accessing ContentProvider from another process id

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, android-8.0-oreo, android-8.1-oreo

I'm getting the following on Android 8 devices when running a content provider operation from another PID:

`Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider null for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority`

When I set the process of the calling Activity to be the same as the main application, I do not get this error. Does anyone have an idea how to do properly invoke the contentprovider from another process id (PID)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include the *complete* Java stack trace, plus all of your code that is tied into the crash.

Comment: Obviously it needs to be exposed system wide with package manager so the Content Provider should have the exported property set to true.